# Xamarin.Forms: how to only allow numbers and dots

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, custom-renderer

I need to only allow numbers and dots to be entered from the keyboard. I created a custom renderer for Android that inherits from EntryRenderer and overriddes the OnElementChanged method as below:

```
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control != null && Element is EntryOnlyNumber entryOnlyNumber)
        {
            string acceptedValue = "1234567890";

            if (entryOnlyNumber.AcceptComma)
                acceptedValue += ",";

            if (entryOnlyNumber.AcceptDot)
                acceptedValue += ".";

            Control.KeyListener = DigitsKeyListener.GetInstance(acceptedValue);
        }
    }
```

This is the code in xaml:

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" 
             Padding="10,20" Spacing="0">
    <Label Text="Indirizzo server:" />
    <controls:EntryOnlyNumber x:Name="EntryAddress" Text="{Binding IdAddress}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" WidthRequest="100" AcceptDot="True"/>       
    <Label Text=":" />       
    <controls:EntryOnlyNumber x:Name="EntryPort" Text="{Binding Port}"
</StackLayout>
```

But this is the result on Android 7:

[image: Keyboard without dot]

As you can see, the dot is missing in the keyboard. What should I do to work around this issue?

Comment: where are you setting the keyboard type?

Comment: I have not set the layout. I left the default

Comment: you have to do something to set the keyboard to numeric

Answer (score 0):

As Jason said that the keyboard that's presented when users interact with an Entry can be set programmatically via the Keyboard property, , to one of the following properties from the Keyboard class:

**Chat** – used for texting and places where emoji are useful.

**Default** – the default keyboard.

**Email** – used when entering email addresses.

**Numeric** – used when entering numbers.

**Plain** – used when entering text, without any KeyboardFlags specified.

**Telephone** – used when entering telephone numbers.

**Text** – used when entering text.

**Url** – used for entering file paths & web addresses.

so you can [customize the keyboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/entry#customize-the-keyboard), don't need to use Entry render.

```
<StackLayout>
        <Entry Keyboard="Numeric" />
    </StackLayout>
```

[image]

**Update:**

You can take a following code:

```
 protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control != null)
        {
            this.Control.KeyListener = DigitsKeyListener.GetInstance("1234567890,.");
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: This suggestion does not satisfy my request because if I set keyboard = numeric, I am not allowed to insert more dots in the entry, for example in case of inserting an ip address. Thats why i am trying to use Entry Render

Comment: As you can see in my initial question, the code I implemented is similar to the one you suggested, but it only works on the emulator, while on a physicals Android 6 or 7 devices the result is shown in the image. So I don't understand this different behavior.

Comment: @Kronos I test my code on Xiao MI Note LTE android 6.0 device, please see my screenshot above.

Comment: I don't undestand. On my LG Q8 device I don't see the dot key. Could be something related to default keyboard layout on my device?

Comment: @Kronos I also test on Google pixel Android 10, it is same as the first screenshot above. So I think it is related to device keyboard layout.